# Command vue init requires a global addon to be installed. Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-init and try again

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

im trying to run:

vue init webpack-simple project

I get the message of the title, so i run the command that the message say but this dont solve my problem.

I understand i have to install vue-cli globally, but i run the differents commands for this and im still on the same.

Here you can see a screenshot from the terminal
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQyJQ.png

Comment: Can you post the error you're seeing in the terminal?

Comment: sure i add the image link, any way it says this: 

  Command vue init requires a global addon to be installed.
  Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-init and try again.

Comment: I saw this same error, after running `npm install -g @vue/cli-init` I didn't have a problem the second time